# Running an exe app from an artifact directory encounters error on command line task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I have a release pipeline that is intended to run an exe app from our internal build agent. See the actual release pipeline task and log below.

Getting this error always Process completed with exit code -2146232576.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running an exe app from an artifact directory encounters error on command line task

Since this issue is related to your specific project and Azure Devops definition settings, we could not give an accurate answer directly, but I would like help to troubleshooting this issue.

To troubleshooting this issue:

First, we should make sure that exe app could be executed successfully on your internal build agent without any issue.

Then, make sure the settings of build definition is correct. As you said in the title, you want to run that exe app from an artifact directory, but you set the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` rather than `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in the Tool option of Command line task.

As test, I create a `HelloWorld.bat` file in my repos, then run it from an artifact directory, following is my test steps:

[image]

[image]

Then I could execute that bat file successfully.

Hope this helps.